# Troubles in text adventure python game

Tags: python-3.x

In my computer's class we were tasked with creating a text adventure game in python. I've gotten something down already, but I could only get so far with my knowledge. I'm probably missing something super simple, but I'm just stuck right now. 
It's a multiple choice deal where the character is presented with 3 options, look around, move or access inventory. I'm stumped at how to make the code go off on it's own tangent.

I have it to where the player can get a description of their surroundings, but if they do and the options come back up, it sort of bugs out and displays the options again and then the next player input stops the code all together. So if the player "Looks around" and then decides they want to "Move" the code stops.

And, in the first area, there are two directions you can go, north and east. Even if you go East and then look around you get the description of what the Northern room looks like.

Also, I need help getting an inventory system fleshed out. I have no idea how i'd do that.

And there are certain times in the game (at least I planned to have them included) where the player could make statements like "Get *insert item here*" how would I create those actions?

Here's the code.

```
import random
import time
print ("You awake in what looks like an adandoned diner with a pounding headache.")

d1a = input ("""What would you like to do?: 
  1. Look around 
  2. Move 
  3. Inventory """)
while d1a != "1" and d1a != "2": 
  #add option 3 to the loop

  d1a = input ("What would you like to do?")

if d1a == "1": 
    print()
    print ("It looks like an old diner. Dust and grime coat the tables, chairs and counter tops. You see a door to the North and another to the East.")
    print()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    d1a = input ("""What would you like to do?: 
  1. Look around 
  2. Move 
  3. Inventory """)




elif d1a == "2":
    d2a = input ("""Where?
    North
    West
    South
    East""")

    while d2a != "North" and d2a != "north" and d2a != "West" and d2a != "west" and d2a != "South" and d2a != "south" and d2a != "East" and d2a != "east":
      d2a = input ("Where?")


    if d2a == "North" or d2a == "north":
      print()
      print ("You go through through the door to the North")
      print ("which has lead to you what looks to be the kitchen")
      print()
      time.sleep(1)

    elif d2a == "East" or d2a == "east":
      print()
      print("You step through the door to the east which")
      print ("takes you out to the streets. They look")
      print ("musty and old, cracks ravaging the asphalt.")
      print()
      time.sleep(1)

    elif d2a == "West" or d2a == "west":
      print()
      print ("I can't move there.")
      print()
      time.sleep(1)

    elif d2a == "South" or d2a == "south":
      print()
      print ("I can't move there.")
      print()
      time.sleep(1)





d1a = input ("""What would you like to do?: 
  1. Look around 
  2. Move 
  3. Inventory """)
while d1a != "1" and d1a != "2": 
  #add option 3 to the loop

  d1a = input ("What would you like to do?")

if d1a == "1": 
    print()
    print ("Must be the kitchen area. You can see stoves, ovens, cabinets containing pots and pans. A dishwasher is open exposing a group of knives. If they're clean or not is unknown.")
    print()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    d1a = input ("""What would you like to do?: 
  1. Look around 
  2. Move 
  3. Inventory """)

elif d1a == "2":
  d2a = input ("""Where?:
  North
  west
  south
  East""")
```

Sorry, I'm relatively new to coding, my class just started delving into it but I wanted to test what I could do with this game.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you move North/east, you should assign a variable, 'location', for example, to the place you move to. then, when you look around, you should use an if statement to see what the location is and then write the correct description.